# How to remove single pixels on the borders of a blob?

Tags: python, c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image like shown below. How do I remove the single pixels on the borders of the blobs?

[image]

No need to give the full code if you don't want to, you can explain some algorithms or point me to the right direction.

Comment: look at [erode/dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20dilate(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue))

Comment: You could do `conv2(your_image, ones(3)) == 4` and then look for clusters of 3 `1`s in a row (or column), the center of that will be your single pixel outcroppings (unless they're on a corner) i.e. `conv2(conv2(your_image, ones(3)) == 4, ones(3)) == 3`

Comment: Erosion, followed by dilation - also known as morphological opening, is the solution if your pixels on the border are of a very small size.

Comment: about erosion/dilation, please see @Jonas objection below (it will eat the 1 pixel line, too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using the hit and miss transform as suggested by midtiby. I used the following kernels to detect the top, right, bottom, and left single-pixels.

```
-1 -1 -1     1 -1 -1      1  1  1     -1 -1  1
-1  1 -1     1  1 -1     -1  1 -1     -1  1  1
 1  1  1     1 -1 -1     -1 -1 -1     -1 -1  1
```

where `-1` represent the background, `1` represent the foreground, and `0` for don't care (not being used in this case).

The result of the four hit and miss transform will be used as the mask to remove the single pixels. Below is the full code in Python/OpenCV:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def hitmiss(src, kernel):
    im = src / 255
    k1 = (kernel == 1).astype('uint8')
    k2 = (kernel == -1).astype('uint8')
    e1 = cv2.erode(im, k1, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    e2 = cv2.erode(1-im, k2, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    return e1 & e2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = cv2.imread('blobs.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    _, im_binary = cv2.threshold(im, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    kernel = np.array([[-1,-1, 1], 
                       [-1, 1, 1], 
                       [-1,-1, 1]])

    im_mask = np.zeros(im_binary.shape, np.uint8)

    im_mask |= hitmiss(im_binary, kernel)
    im_mask |= hitmiss(im_binary, np.fliplr(kernel))
    im_mask |= hitmiss(im_binary, kernel.T)
    im_mask |= hitmiss(im_binary, np.flipud(kernel.T))

    im_dst = im_binary & ((1 - im_mask) * 255)
    cv2.imwrite('dst.png', im_dst)
```

Given this input image:

[image]

The script will produce this output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a task for the [hit and miss transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm).

Comment: please avoid "link-only" answers, as the link may stop work in the future. See [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: yes this is the task of hit and miss transform. I posted the full code on my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform a [erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#erosion) operation followed by [dialation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#dilation) operation on given Image. Somehow example images on these links are oppsite, so dont get confused.

Erosion will shrink your white areas with appropriate filter. It will remove extra white pixels. Then you can dialate to expand white areas again but without extra white noisy pixels.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will also remove the single-pixel horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

My method to remove such single pixels is to check **4-connected neighbors** around each pixel. If a pixel only has one neighbor, it will be removed. This will erase one pixel at the edge of the "rotated L" as well which is not expected to be removed.

Here is my code to implement my method above:

```
    int neighborNum;
    vector<cv::Point> willRemove;
    for (int i = 1; i < img.rows - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < img.cols - 1; j++) {
            neighborNum = 0;
            if (img.at<uchar>(i, j) == 255) {
                // Check 4 connected neighbors
                if (img.at<uchar>(i, j - 1) == 255) {
                    neighborNum++;
                }
                if (img.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) == 255) {
                    neighborNum++;
                }
                if (img.at<uchar>(i, j + 1) == 255) {
                    neighborNum++;
                }
                if (img.at<uchar>(i + 1, j) == 255) {
                    neighborNum++;
                }
                // Found! 
                if (neighborNum == 1) {
                    willRemove.push_back(cv::Point(j, i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Try to remove pixels now    
    for (int i = 0; i < willRemove.size(); i++) {
        cv::circle(img, willRemove[i], 0, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }
```

Comment: you only check for neighbours==1 . imho it needs exaxtly 3

Comment: @berak, in his code he checks N4 neighborhood so the neighborNum is indeed should be 1 (not 3).

Comment: @WangYudong some other undesired pixels might be removed (like center pixel in Y shape, etc...)