# Remove character-noise with OpenCV/Scikit image

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I am having trouble finding an algorithm that could remove those "pixel" noise attached to the letters shown in the image below.

I've tried opening functions however the results are not as great as I would expect... Has anyone found any situation similar to this one?

[image]

Comment: This should solve it. The main algorithm that is proposed here is hit and miss algorithm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238308/how-to-remove-single-pixels-on-the-borders-of-a-blob

Comment: If you want to classify these characters, it's better to consider those noises.

Comment: @Batselot, that was perfect!! Thanks my man